# How to create LinphoneConferenceParams in android?

Tags: android, linphone

`createconference` is a method of Linphone, this method has a parameter called `Linphoneconferenceparams` , so I have to create this parameter. How to create LinphoneConferenceParams in android?

Answer (score 0):

Linphoneconferenceparams is an interface and you have to implement it to use methods of this interface. Make LinphoneCore object using:

```
LinphoneCore lc=LinphoneManager.getLc();
```

Than use:

```
lc.createConference(this);
```

or don't implement Linphoneconferenceparams in your activity and direct use this:-

```
lc.createConference(new Linphoneconferenceparams(){
     //here is interface methods
});
```

For more details, check this tutorial on Linphone [Part-1](http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/04/start-working-on-linphone-android-part-1.html) and [Part-2](http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/06/android-linphone-source-code-tutorial.html).

Comment: lc.createConference(this); I got error here , they recommended Linphoneconferenceparams instead of context (this)